# How to Transfer All Greasemonkey userscripts to Tampermonkey on Firefox 57+

Tags: greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4, firefox-57+

After read that [Greasemonkey recommends users to install Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).

I've installed Tampermonkey and now I'm trying to transfer all my Greasemonkey 3.x scripts to be opened on Tampermonkey, but I can't find it's location or even how to do it.

I've read this [question that says where and how it's located on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850460/where-are-chrome-tampermonkey-userscripts-stored-on-the-filesystem), but where is it on Firefox 57+?
How can I transfer it?

PS: *I'm expecting I won't need to update every userscript I have.*

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Based on derjanb comment I'm answering the question showing the steps I took to achieve the transfer of the userscripts.

1. Enter **about:support** on firefox address, then find and click open folder

[image: about:support]

---

2. Now find and open **gm_scripts** folder, click to search inside it and type **.user.js**, when the search finishes select all userscripts you want to transfer.

[image: searching for .user.js files]

---

3. Now right click the selected files and choose [Send To - Compressed (zipped) folder.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14200/windows-compress-uncompress-zip-files)

[image: zip]
[image]

---

4. Once your zip file is created find it on Desktop or where it was created and open the Tampermonkey Dashboard

[image: dashboard]

---

5. Go to utilities tab and on Zip select import, find your zip file and once you click open button, it should load

[image: import]

---

5. Finally a list with all scripts inside the zip should open, asking which one you desire to import. If you want all, just click import.

[image: list of userscripts to install under this]

That should do it. Check it out on Installed userscripts tab.

Comment: I'm sorry. It looks like I didn't know how to do it, before my comment I searched how to make a Community Wiki answer and the link I saw said I should just flag it to a moderator change it, and that was what I did. *Edited I just saw it on edit mode*.

Comment: I couldn't find the user scripts in the profiles folder. But there is a simpler method to export/import, see my answer.

Answer (score 7):

How to export scripts from **Greasemonkey** to a zip file:

1. Click the Greasemonkey plugin
2. Click *Export a backup...*
3. Save file

How to import scripts to **Tampermonkey** from a zip file:

1. Click the Tampermonkey plugin
2. Click *Dashboard*
3. Navigate to *Utilities* tab
4. Click *Browse...* under *Zip* menu
5. Select the exported zip file
6. Click *Import*

Comment: THANK YOU! There's no gm_scripts folder in my profile, for some reason, so I had no way to follow the other answer's instructions. And this technique is WAY better, too!