# Greasemonkey script folder missing

Tags: greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

I am following the instructions to transfer Greasemonkey scripts to Tampermonkey:  [How to Transfer All Greasemonkey userscripts to Tampermonkey on Firefox 57+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317983/how-to-transfer-all-greasemonkey-userscripts-to-tampermonkey-on-firefox-57). However the folder "gm_scripts" mentioned in the instructions does not exist on my PC.

Here are the folders that I do have (Click for larger view):

[image: folder screenshot]

Would you know which of these the scripts may be in?

I am a beginner at using scripts and maybe this is not really necessary, but it is good practice for me.

Comment: How many Greasemonkey scripts did you have installed before switching to *either* Firefox 57+ *or* Greasemonkey 4+?   What versions of Greasemonkey did you have installed, and which version do you have installed now?

Answer (score 11):

Apparently GreaseMonkey no longer stores the user scripts in `gm_scripts` for Firefox. I have *Firefox 58* with *GreaseMonkey 4.2*. I manually added some junk data to one of the user scripts, followed by comparing file sizes for any changed files in AppData, and what I discovered is that the scripts are apparently stored in an SQLite database file located at:

`C:\Users\[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[ID].default\storage\default\moz-extension+++[GUID]\idb\[Number]gyreekansoem.sqlite`

I then proceeded to open the database file using a tool called *DB Browser for SQLite*. Inside the database, the GreaseMonkey user scripts appear to be stored within the `object_data` table under the `data` field. The data format is unfortunately not plain text, so I am not sure how exactly to fetch the JavaScript directly from this database field.

Comment: Wow, these Firefox WebExtensions have made Greasemonkey even more painful to use than I expected. Ranting at the embedded script editor, I thought "no problem, I'll just go to the gm_script directory and use my editor, as usual"… and here I am. Thanks for investigating.

Comment: This and other Greasemonkey limitations given by API changes in Firefox 57 and above are officially described at https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-script-authors.html.

Comment: More info regarding recovery can be found at https://groups.google.com/g/greasemonkey-users/c/3Om1PUbeZzA?pli=1 and at http://randomizd.blogspot.com/2019/05/greasemonkey-script-recovery-getting.html

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to export all the userscripts, there's a menu item called `Export a backup...` in the current version of Greasemonkey (tested with version 4.8). This exports all the scripts' folders and files into a ZIP file.