# How to debug Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey userscripts with FF 57+ (with WebExtensions)?

Tags: debugging, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts, firefox-57+

I can't find my userscript(s) in the Browser Debugger's *Open file...* box (with the name defined at `// @name`).

It seems that [Annarfych's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40764515/1744774) and [Hjulle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39214862/1744774) to [How to debug Greasemonkey script with the Firebug extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3490062/1744774) do not work any more.

Because of [Michael's findings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851793/1744774) to [Greasemonkey script folder missing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48469729/1744774)?

> Apparently GreaseMonkey no longer stores the user scripts in `gm_scripts` for Firefox. [...] the scripts are apparently stored in an SQLite database file.

Comment: The problem is even worse: even when you find a file using, say, XHR breakpoint and choose `Reveal in the tree` context item from tab header menu - nothing will show up in the source tree.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no answer until now:

- Open DevTools (<kbd>F12</kbd>) > Debugger
- The userscripts for Tampermonkey are stored in the addon folder `Tampermonkey` > `userscripts` folder
- For Greasemonkey the UserScripts are stored in the folder `user-script://` > the namespace of the userscript > userscript name

Comment: In my FF 92.0.1's _Debugger_ → _Sources_ there is a _Main-Thread_ → _Tampermonkey_ folder with two files: `rea/common.js`, `content.js` and there is no _Greasemonkey_ folder at all. There are folders for other add-ons I have installed: _Native MathML_, _uMatrix_, etc.