# Not able to import a GM user.js file into tampermonkey

Tags: firefox-addon, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, greasemonkey-4

I am attempting to move my GM scripts to tampermonkey following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47317983/how-to-transfer-all-greasemonkey-userscripts-to-tampermonkey-on-firefox-57) post.

I have exported my scripts from GM as a zip folder, duplicated the user.js file, compressed it as a zip file, and tried importing Both the zipped user.js file And the plain js file **separately**, and both times tampermonkey didnt take them.

For the plain js file, it gave me a "unable to parse this" message and for the zipped file, its just a spinning wheel of death. Tampermonkey forums seems to be down [also](https://forum.tampermonkey.net/viewtopic.php?t=983)

Any help on sorting this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are them too many scripts? Doesn't copy/paste work?

Answer (score 0):

TamperMonkey changed the Javascript library that they are using to import and export zip files. Unfortunately, it looks like when Tampermonkey tries to import from the zip, it returns an unhandled null value when it reads from a directory. I haven't found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the zip file does not contain any folder. This means all your *.user.js files have to be located a the zip's root level.

At Windows 10 this means you have to go to the GM folder, select all .user.js files, open the context menu and click "Send To" and "Compressed (zipped) folder". This will generate an importable zip file.

Note: this issue will be fixed at the next beta and stable version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue as well...

```
Tampermonkey Unable to parse this! :(
```

**What Action I took to solve this :**

> I had one **large** Zip file , Divided it into **3 small chunks** and imported and it again 3 times one by one (chunk wise chunk) and it was successful.

***- Pathetic experience with tampermonkey  always in Import/Export***

[image: Tampermonkey Unable to parse this! :(]